# URL amigável htaccess PHP

Tags: php, htaccess, url-amigável

Fala galera, tudo blz?

Tenho o seguinte htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /pasta1/pasta2/
RewriteRule ^([0-9A-z_-]+)/(.*)/(.*)/ detalhes_item.php?id_param_1=$2&id_param_2=$3
RewriteRule ^([0-9A-z_-]+)/(.*)/(.*) detalhes_item.php?id_param_1=$2&id_param_2=$3
```

Com este htaccess, consegui converte essa url:
http://meusite.com.br/pasta1/pasta1/detalhes_item.php?id_param_1=145&id_param_2=66

para:
http://meusite.com.br/pasta1/pasta1/texto-dinamico/145/66/

O problema é que agora não consigo abrir a URL de imagem, exemplo:

http://meusite.com.br/pasta1/pasta2/images/produtos/4104.jpg

Ao tentar abrir a URL acima, abre a página de detalhe do produto.

OBS.: Essa parte: "RewriteBase /pasta1/pasta2/" é pq eu tenho um wordpress na pasta raiz do servidor.

Alguém, por favor, pode dar uma luz?

Obrigado

Answer (score 0):

acrescente essa linha ao seu .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.jpeg|\.jpg|\.gif|\.png)$ [NC]
```

assim a reescrita vai ignorar as imagens.